# is there Markdown webpart for sharepoint 2016 on prem?

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-on-prem, sharepoint-server

I am looking for a way to store markdown code in SharePoint. Is there a way to keep markdown in SharePoint and display it properly?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out these client side webparts (spfx) for SharePoint?

- [spfx-markdown-webpart](https://github.com/kmees/spfx-markdown-webpart)
- [SPFx Fantastic 40 Web Parts](https://github.com/OlivierCC/spfx-40-fantastics)

The instructions are for Office 365 though...